# How can i bypass a if instruction by injecting a variable

Tags: bash, security, code-injection, quoting

How can I bypass this instruction

```
if test $TEST -eq ${1} 2>/dev/null; then
```

by injecting code?
I tried some injection when I run the script like:

```
./script.sh '1 || 1 = 1 '
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: I mean to make the if turn True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-o` instead of `||`, you want `test` to interpret the value of the variable, not the shell.

```
./script.sh '1 -o 1 = 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply run your script by

```
TEST=4711 ./script.sh 4711
```

Comment: Psychodemon: It **does** work. You must have done something wrong. See [this](https://user.fm/files/v2-69e4eff53d7b546aed6dd6dde0534e3b/capture_20201105_120930.jpg) screenshot which demonstrates the case.

Comment: Yes, now it work, but I must not modify the content of the TEST variable

Comment: Why not? And, if you suddenly have new restrictions for your problem to observe, I suggest that you answer a new question, because the question in the way you have written it, would be solved by my answer.